# Nondeterministic Pushdown Automata different diagrams

Tags: non-deterministic, context-free-language, pushdown-automaton, automata-theory

In introduction to the theory of computation book, for the language  [image: formula] a state diagram is given as :

[image]

I know there could be alternative diagrams but I doubt the solution I found might be wrong which is slightly different than the original one:
[image]

I would appreciate any counter inputs for my solution.

Comment: Your transition diagram does not allow for the empty string to be accepted by your PDA, whereas the book's diagram does. The empty string is a member of the target language, so the book's is correct and yours is not.

Comment: @Welbog my diagram also allows for empty state since q1 is accept state in my case thus when string is empty which means no input, one branch will stay at q1 and accept the empty string.

Comment: Ah, I see that. You're right. I believe they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Can't bear to see an unanswered question. So Yes they are equivalent with what I have observed.